# Remote validation with viewmodels. List properties in viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation

I am trying to do remote validation on some properties in my booking web application.

```
public class ReservationVM
{
    public Rsvn ReservationInfo { get; set; } // Model for Reservation
    public AdminFilterRsvn FilterAdmin { get; set; } // Model for Filter in Admin Panel ???
    public IEnumerable<Rsvn> ReservationQuery { get; set; } // Query of All Reservations in Database
    public IEnumerable<AvailableRooms> AvailableRooms { get; set; } // Query of All Free and Reserved Rooms SearchResult View
    public List<Room> RoomList { get; set; } // List of Rooms
    public List<Guest> GuestList { get; set; } // List of Guests

}
```

The view for that VM is:

```
@model Reservations.ViewModels.Reservation.ReservationVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reservation";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MakeReservationLayoutPage.cshtml";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { @id = string.Empty }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "rsvnForm" }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class="text-danger"})
    <div id="rsvnInfo" class="container border border-danger">
        <br />
        <h5 class="text-center">Обща информация за резервацията</h5>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="form_label">Смяна</span>

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReservationInfo.Period)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReservationInfo.Period, Model.ReservationInfo.PeriodList, "Изберете смяна", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dropDownList", @readonly = true, @disabled = "disabled" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ReservationInfo.Period, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="from-label">Дата от</span>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.ReservationInfo.BegDATE, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @id = "BegDATE", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Начална дата", @readonly = true })*@
                        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.ReservationInfo.BegDATE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "BegDATE", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Начална дата", @readonly = true } })*@
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.ReservationInfo.BegDATEDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "BegDATE", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Начална дата", @readonly = true } })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model=>Model.ReservationInfo.BegDATE)
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReservationInfo.BegDATEDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="from-label">Дата до</span>
                        <div class="form-group">


                            @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.ReservationInfo.EndDATE, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @id = "EndDATE", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Начална дата", @readonly = true })*@
                            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.ReservationInfo.EndDATE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "EndDATE", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Крайна дата", @readonly = true } })*@
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.ReservationInfo.EndDATEDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "EndDATE", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Крайна дата", @readonly = true } })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ReservationInfo.EndDATE)
                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReservationInfo.EndDATEDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="form_label">Възрастни</span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReservationInfo.Adults, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", min = 0, @readonly = true } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReservationInfo.Adults, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="form_label">Деца</span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReservationInfo.Kids, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", min = 0, @readonly = true } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReservationInfo.Kids, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="form_label">Брой стай</span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReservationInfo.Rooms, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", min = 1, @readonly = true } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReservationInfo.Rooms, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="form_label">Направил резервация</span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ReservationInfo.RsvnMaker, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @readonly = true } })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="form_label">Брой нощувки</span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ReservationInfo.Nights, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @readonly = true } })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReservationInfo.TotalPrice)
    </div>

    for (int index = 0; index < Model.RoomList.Count; index++)
    {
        <br />
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RoomList[index].IsMainRoom);
        var room = index + 1;

        if (index == 0)
        {

            <div class="container border ">
                <br />
                <h5 class="text-center">Информация относно стая номер @room</h5>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Изберете тип стая</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomType, Model.RoomList[index].RoomTypeList, new
                       {@class = "form-control invent roomtype", @id = "roomTypeDropDownList" + index})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Описание на стая</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomView, Model.RoomList[index].RoomViewList, new
                       {@class = "form-control roomview",
                           @id = "roomViewDropDownList" + index})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomView, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Изберете етаж</label>

                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomFloor, Model.RoomList[index].RoomFloorList, "Изберете етаж", new{@class = "form-control roomlevel",
                       @id = "roomLevelDropDownList" + index})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomFloor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Изберете номер на стая</label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomID, Model.RoomList[index].RoomIDList, "Изберете стая", new{@class = "form-control roomid",
                       @id = "roomIdDropDownList" + index})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
        }
        else
        {

            <div class="container border ">
                <h5 class="text-center">Информация относно стая номер @room</h5>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Изберете тип стая</label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomType, Model.RoomList[index].RoomTypeList, "Изберете тип стая", new{@class = "form-control invent roomtype",
                       @id = "roomTypeDropDownList" + index})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Изберете изглед стая</label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomView, Model.RoomList[index].RoomViewList, "Изберете изглед на стая", new{@class = "form-control roomview",
                       @id = "roomViewDropDownList" + index})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomView, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Изберете етаж</label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomFloor, Model.RoomList[index].RoomFloorList, "Изберете етаж", new{@class = "form-control roomlevel",
                       @id = "roomLevelDropDownList" + index })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomFloor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Изберете номер на стая</label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomID, Model.RoomList[index].RoomIDList, "Изберете стая", new{@class = "form-control roomid",
                       @id = "roomIdDropDownList" + index})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoomList[index].RoomID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < Model.GuestList.Count; j++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GuestList[j].IsMainGuest);
        var text = "";
        var k = j + 1;
        if (j == 0)
        {
            text = "Въведете вашите данни";
        }
        else
        {
            text = "Въведете данни относно гост номер " + k;
        }
        <br />
        <div class="container border ">
            <br />
            <h5 class="text-center">@text</h5>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Име</label>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GuestList[j].FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @placeholder = "Име" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GuestList[j].FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Презиме</label>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GuestList[j].LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @placeholder = "Презиме" } })
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Фамилия</label>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GuestList[j].FamilyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @placeholder = "Фамилия" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GuestList[j].FamilyName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Тип гост</label>
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.GuestList[j].PersonType, "Изберете тип", new { @class = "form-control guesttype", @id = "guestType" + j })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GuestList[j].PersonType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Възраст</label>
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.GuestList[j].PersonAge, "Изберете възраст", new { @class = "form-control guestview", @id = "guestView" + j })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GuestList[j].PersonAge, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Пол</label>
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.GuestList[j].Gender, "Изберете пол", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GuestList[j].Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Телефонен номер</label>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GuestList[j].PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @placeholder = "+359...." } })
                        <small id="phoneHelpInline" class="text-muted">
                            Моля пишете си номера с +359 отпред...
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label>ЕГН</label>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GuestList[j].EGN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @placeholder = "ЕГН" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GuestList[j].EGN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <small id="egnHelpInline" class="text-muted">
                            ЕГН
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Дата на раждане</label>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GuestList[j].BirthDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control birthdate", @placeholder = "Дата на раждане" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GuestList[j].BirthDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <small id="birthDateHelpInline" class="text-muted">
                            Дата на раждане
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Стая</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GuestList[j].GuestRoomID, Model.GuestList[j].GuestRoomIDList, "Изберете номер на стая", new{@class = "form-control guestroomid",
                       @id = "guestRoomId" + j})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GuestList[j].GuestRoomID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>

    }
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-btn">
                    <input class="submit-btn btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="submitRsvn" type="button" value="Направи резервация" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-btn">
                    <input class="submit-btn btn btn-outline-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" name="button" value="Към търсачка" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="messageBox" style="display:none">
        @if (Model.RoomList.Count == 1)
        {
            <p class="text-center">
                Стаята която избрахте в момента е налична.
                Побързайте да финализирате вашата резервация, преди някои да го направи преди вас.
                Ще бъде изчислена цената, която трябва да заплатите в срок от 5 дни.
            </p>
            <p class="text-center">Продължи?</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p class="text-center">
                Стаите които избрахте в момента са налични.
                Побързайте да финализирате вашата резервация, преди някои да го направи преди вас.
                Ще бъде изчислена цената, която трябва да заплатите в срок от 5 дни.
            </p>
            <p class="text-center">Продължи?</p>
        }

    </div>

    <div id="validationFalse" style="display:none">
        @if (Model.RoomList.Count == 1)
        {
            <p class="text-center">
                Стаята която избрахте, в момента беше запазена от друг.
                Съжаляваме за случилото се. Моля изберете друга стая.
            </p>
            <p class="text-center">Ще направим всичко възможно да си намерите стая която ве устройва.</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p class="text-center">
                Една или повече от стаите които запазихте, в момента бяха запазени от друг.
                Съжаляваме за случилото се. Моля изберете други стаи.
            </p>
            <p class="text-center">Ще направим всичко възможно да си намерите стая която ве устройва.</p>
        }

    </div>

    <div id="roomsNotSelected" style="display:none">
        @if (Model.RoomList.Count == 1)
        {
            <p class="text-center">
                Моля първо изберете номер на стая.
            </p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p class="text-center">
                Моля, изберете стаи в които искате да гостувате.
            </p>
        }

    </div>
}
```

The validation that i am trying to do are on Guest Mode which is:

```
public class Guest
    {
        public int? GusetID { get; set; }
        public string ReservationID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Въведете име")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Въведете семейно име")]
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [EnumDataType(typeof(PersonType), ErrorMessage = "Въведете тип гост")]
        public PersonType PersonType { get; set; }
        [EnumDataType(typeof(PersonAge), ErrorMessage = "Въведете възраст")]
        public PersonAge PersonAge { get; set; }
        [EnumDataType(typeof(Gender), ErrorMessage = "Въведете пол")]
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Полето ЕГН не може да бъде празно")]
        [Remote("IsCorrectEGN", "Reservation", HttpMethod ="POST", ErrorMessage = "Въведете правилно ЕГН.")]
        public string EGN { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Въведете дата на раждане")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Въведете номер на стая")]
        [Remote("CheckPersonAge", "Reservation", HttpMethod ="POST", ErrorMessage = "Възраста която въведохте, не съответсва с тип гост.")]
        public int? GuestRoomID { get; set; }
        public char? IsMainGuest { get; set; }

        public string PersonTypeDescription { get; set; }
        public string PersonAgeDescription { get; set; }
        public string PersonGenderDescription { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PersonTypeList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PersonAgeList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PersonGenderList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GuestRoomIDList { get; set; }
    }
```

The validation code is in ReservationController:

```
public JsonResult IsCorrectEGN(ReservationVM Reservation)
        {
            Reservation
            string EGN = null;
            string[] ListEGN = new string[Reservation.GuestList.Count];

            for (int index = 0; index < Reservation.GuestList.Count; index++)
            {
                EGN = Reservation.GuestList[index].EGN;
                //ListEGN[index] = Reservation.GuestList[index].EGN;


            }

            return Json(CheckEGN(EGN), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public bool CheckEGN(string EGN)
        {
            DbManager db = new DbManager();
            int result = db.CheckIfEGNISValid(EGN);
            bool isValidEgn = false;

            if (result == 1)
                isValidEgn = true;

            return isValidEgn;
        }
```

And CheckEGN(param) is calling db method which sends EGN to Oracle DB and returns 1 if it is okay, and 0 if it is false. The DB method is below:

```
public int CheckIfEGNISValid(string egn)
        {

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("", GetDBConnection());

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.BindByName = true;

            OracleParameter ret = new OracleParameter();
            ret.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(ret);

            cmd.CommandText = @"select s_checks.is_EGN(:str_inp) from dual";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(GetStringParameter(egn, "str_inp"));
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(GetNotNullableDateParameter(begDate, "p_beg_date"));
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(GetNotNullableDateParameter(endDate, "p_end_date"));
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ret.Value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            closeDBConnection();

            var result = Convert.ToInt32(ret.Value.ToString());

            return result;

        }
```

I understand the concept of remote validation is MVC if i work with simple data. By simple data i mean not Lists etc.. The thing here is that i can have X guests and i need to check if they enter valid PersonID(EGN).
My code so far works only for the first guest. For the 2nd, 3th ... Nth the ReservationVM is null. So no data is passed from view to controller with AJAX.

How can i make my validation to check for every guest. I am open to any suggestions. I am still new with ASP.NET and still have a lot to learn.

So this is what happens for the first item in the list, first EGN reaches the controller[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nG6j.png)

And for the second:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaTE7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add these scripts in `view`

```html
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) maybe helpful for you

Comment: Well i did check this, i was only missing the last one:
<script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
But that didn't solve the problem...

Comment: I added two photos of what is happening. For the first item(guest) EGN is passed, but for the next the VM is null. So nothing is being passed.

Comment: Thanks your answer also helped for me. But what did the thing was i changed my method code:
public JsonResult IsCorrectEGN()
{
var EGN = Request.Form[Request.Form.AllKeys.First(p=>p.Contains("Guest"))];
return Json(CheckEGN(EGN), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}